# take the part of line using regex

Tags: regex

i have a line like this:
*Re: [#244] New Employee .. text text 785 text*

How I can get number, between "[#   ]" ?
If I write `\d\d\d` it's not be right.

Comment: you actually want to extract the number?

Comment: i need mutch number only between the square brackets (first mutch in line)

Comment: Hope that you need to extract any number of digits between **[#** and **]** . Where are you using this regex?

Comment: if you want to extract use javascript split function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want all digits between the square brackets after the #.

Regex: `(?=\[#(\d+)\])`

Try this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dC1sA2/2)